# Programmatically Push VC on Table Row Tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, row

I am attempting to do a `onRowTap` method without using a storyboard segue to push to a new View Controller, however when tapped it only displays information from the first item of the indexPath no matter which row is tapped. Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
    NSInteger row = [[self tableView].indexPathForSelectedRow row];
    NSDictionary *insta = [self.instaPics objectAtIndex:row];
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    InstaPicDetailViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InstagramDetail"];
    vc.detailItem = insta;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your deslectRowAtIndexPath message call below the assignment of your row variable:

```
NSInteger row = [[self tableView].indexPathForSelectedRow row];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```